# What is a SaveSet in XWindows

Tags: x11

I can see the man pages for those functions:

```
   XChangeSaveSet, XAddToSaveSet, XRemoveFromSaveSet - change a client's save set
```

But it never bothers to explain what a "Save Set" actually is, so what is it, what's the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Controlling_the_Lifetime_of_a_Window
defines a save set as:

> The *save-set* of a client is a list of other clients' windows that, if
>   they are inferiors of one of the client's windows at connection close,
>   should not be destroyed and should be remapped if they are unmapped.
>   For further information about close-connection processing, see [section 2.6](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Using_X_Server_Connection_Close_Operations).
>   To allow an application's window to survive when a window manager that has reparented a window fails, Xlib provides the save-set
>   functions that you can use to control the longevity of subwindows that
>   are normally destroyed when the parent is destroyed. For example, a
>   window manager that wants to add decoration to a window by adding a
>   frame might reparent an application's window. When the frame is
>   destroyed, the application's window should not be destroyed but be
>   returned to its previous place in the window hierarchy.

Comment: Does it mean this feature is only supposed to be used by a window manager developers?